# I need to change the text value in the <type> nodes to

Tags: php, xml, replace

I'm importing from different xml files.

example structure:

1)
1-sample.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
<kyero>
<feed_version>3</feed_version>
</kyero>

<property>
<type><![CDATA[Detached Villa]]></type>
<town>Ciudad Quesada</town>
</property>

<property>
<type><![CDATA[Semi Detached Villa]]></type>
<town>Benijofar</town>
</property>
</root>
```

2. 

2-sample.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
<kyero>
<feed_version>3</feed_version>
</kyero>

<property>
<type>semi-detached-villa</type>
<town>Villena</town>
</property>

<property>
<type>Semi</type>
<town>Elda</town>
</property>
</root>
```

3. 

3-sample.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
<kyero>
<feed_version>3</feed_version>
</kyero>

<property>
<type>Semi-Detached House</type>
<town>Villena</town>
</property>

<property>
<type>Semi - Detached Villa</type>
<town>Elda</town>
</property>
</root>
```

I need to change the text value in the  nodes to SemiDetached.
I'm using the str_replace function.

```
function house_type_propertynew($type){
$type = str_replace('Semi Detached Villa', 'SemiDetached', $type);
$type = str_replace('Detached Villa', 'SemiDetached', $type);
$type = str_replace('Semi-Detached House', 'SemiDetached', $type);
$type = str_replace('Semi', 'SemiDetached', $type);
$type = str_replace('Semi-Detached House', 'SemiDetached', $type);
$type = str_replace('Semi - Detached Villa', 'SemiDetached', $type);
return $type;}
```

The result is several values instead of "SemiDetached":

SemiDetached - SemiDetached
SemiDetachedDetached
SemiDetached-detached

That is, the text is duplicated, mixed up, folded differently but does not give the desired “SemiDetached” result!

I would like to clarify that in xml files there are other values in  nodes that need to be changed to other text values, and there are also values in  nodes that do not need to be changed.

An example of what needs to be changed:

```
function house_type_propertynew($type){
$type = str_replace('Parking Space', 'garage', $type);
$type = str_replace('Apartamento', 'Apartment', $type);
$type = str_replace('Ground Floor', 'Apartment', $type);
$type = str_replace('Flat', 'Apartment', $type);
$type = str_replace('detached house', 'SemiDetached', $type);
$type = str_replace('Semi', 'SemiDetached', $type);
$type = str_replace('Detached Villa', 'SemiDetached', $type);
$type = str_replace('Semi-detached', 'SemiDetached', $type);
$type = str_replace('Semi-Detached House', 'SemiDetached', $type);
$type = str_replace('semi-detached-villa', 'SemiDetached', $type);
$type = str_replace('Semi - Detached Villa', 'SemiDetached', $type);
$type = str_replace('Terraced house', 'Town House', $type);
$type = str_replace('Townhouse', 'Town House', $type);
$type = str_replace('terraced house', 'Town House', $type);
$type = str_replace('House – Townhouse', 'Town House', $type);
$type = str_replace('Quad Bungalow', 'Quad', $type);
$type = str_replace('Quad House', 'Quad', $type);
$type = str_replace('Quadplex', 'Quad', $type);
$type = str_replace('Quad Villa', 'Quad', $type);
$type = str_replace('Chalet', 'Villa', $type);
$type = str_replace('Chalets Pareados', 'Villa', $type);
$type = str_replace('Village house', 'Villa', $type);
$type = str_replace('Village House', 'Villa', $type);
$type = str_replace('Villa with annex', 'Villa', $type);
$type = str_replace('Villas Pareados', 'Villa', $type);
$type = str_replace('Finca / Country Property', 'Country Estate', $type);
$type = str_replace('finca', 'Country Estate', $type);
$type = str_replace('Country Property/Finca', 'Country Estate', $type);
$type = str_replace('Country Property', 'Country Estate', $type);
$type = str_replace('Country House', 'Country Estate', $type);
$type = str_replace('Plot of Land', 'Plot', $type);
$type = str_replace('Building Plot', 'Plot', $type);
$type = str_replace('land', 'Plot', $type);
$type = str_replace('Land', 'Plot', $type);
$type = str_replace('Restoration Project', 'Plot', $type);
$type = str_replace('Duplex apartment', 'Duplex', $type);
$type = str_replace('Bar', 'Restaurants and Bars', $type);
$type = str_replace('Bar/Restaurant', 'Restaurants and Bars', $type);
$type = str_replace('Commercial Unit', 'commercial', $type);
$type = str_replace('Commercial Building', 'commercial', $type);
$type = str_replace('Locales Comerciales', 'commercial', $type);
$type = str_replace('Business premises', 'commercial', $type);
$type = str_replace('Bungalows Planta Baja', 'Bungalow', $type);
$type = str_replace('Bungalows Planta Alta', 'Bungalow', $type);
return $type;}
```

What am I doing wrong?

So it replaces all values with SemiDetached, it doesn't work!

```
function house_type_propertynew($type){
$type = preg_replace('/<type>(.*?)<\/type>/', '<type>SemiDetached</type>', $type);
return $type;}
```

Answer (score 1):

The way you have written your `str_replace` commands, they are cumulative.  So if you start with 'Semi Detached Villa', that gets transformed by the first `str_replace` to 'SemiDetached'.

However, a few lines later we search for 'Semi' and replace that with 'SemiDetached', so our string is now 'SemiDetachedDetached'... and so on.

Alternatively you could use `preg_replace` for more sophisticated pattern matching.  Perhaps something like:

```php
return preg_replace('/^Semi([ -]?Detached([ -]?(House|Villa))?)?$/i', 'SemiDetached', $type);
```

Comment: Passing an array into `str_replace` will still process the matches sequentially; your example only avoids this because you've skipped the problematic "Semi" search term.

Comment: I didn't realise that.  Thanks.  I will modify my answer to omit that part.